# problemas mostrando resultados en una tabla

Tags: php, pdo

tengo un problema a la hora de mostrar registros en mi tabla el problema es el siguiente: en la cabecera de la tabla muestro las horas que seria ocho en total y abajo de la cabecera se muestran los resultados de los números que han salido de acuerdo a la hora y al día, pero el problema surje que la primera semana del día jueves se registraron unos datos y ahora la segunda semana del día jueves se deben registrar los otros datos de ese mismo día pero se me sigue mostrando en la misma fila cuando debería mostrarse abajo porque se supone que son el mismo día pero diferentes resultados anexo una imagen y para mostrar como debería quedar y mi error presentado actualmente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**código fuente**

```
<div id="test5" class="center-align light">

    <?php
    $consulta = $DB_con->query("SELECT * FROM hora_sorteo");
    for ($set = array (); $row = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $set[] = $row);
    ?>
   <table  class='striped responsive-table centered'>
   <thead>
   <tr>
   <?php for($i=0;$i<count($set);$i++){
echo "<th>" . $set[$i]['hora_sorteo'] . "</th>"; //muestra las horas de jugada
   }?>
   </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php
    $consulta2 = $DB_con->query("SELECT 
    animalitos.id,
    animalitos.numero,
    resultado.id,
    resultado.fk_animalitos,
    resultado.fk_hora_sorteo,
    resultado.fk_dias,
    resultado.fecha,
    hora_sorteo.id,
    hora_sorteo.hora_sorteo,
    dias.id,
    dias.dias
           FROM animalitos 
                INNER JOIN resultado ON animalitos.id=resultado.fk_animalitos  
                INNER JOIN hora_sorteo ON resultado.fk_hora_sorteo=hora_sorteo.id
                INNER JOIN dias ON resultado.fk_dias=dias.id
                WHERE resultado.fk_dias='5'  ORDER BY resultado.id ");
           for ($set2 = array (); $row = $consulta2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $set2[] = $row);
              ?>
          <tr>
         <?php for($b=0;$b<count($set2);$b++){
         echo "<td>" . $set2[$b]['numero'] . "</td>"; //muestra los 
         resultados de los numeros
           }?>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: No entiendo por qué quieres presentar dos filas con los mismos resultados (imagen 3). ¿Podrías dar más detalles de lo que quieres hacer? Quizá haya un problema al enfocar el problema y la forma de resolverlo. Es importante que digas si los datos tienen que estar agrupados , por ejemplo.

Comment: no son los mismos resultado es un ejemplo de como quiero que se me muestren los resultados el mes tiene 4 semanas y eso equivale a 4 filas de cada dia

Comment: no son los mismos resultado es un ejemplo de como quiero que se me muestren los resultados el mes tiene 4 semanas y eso equivale a 4 filas de cada día serian 4 lunes, 4 martes, 4 miércoles, etc, entonces lo que quiero es mostrar los resultados de esos días que es lo que hace la consulta pero mi problema es que se me muestran los datos en la misma linea me explico se me muestran los 4 jueves en la misma linea, cuando debería mostrarse 4 lineas por día.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solución es esta

```
<div id="test6" class="center-align light">

    <?php
    $consulta = $DB_con->query("SELECT * FROM hora_sorteo");
    for ($set = array (); $row = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $set[] = $row);
 ?>
 <table  class='striped responsive-table centered'>
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <?php for($i=0;$i<count($set);$i++){
echo "<th>" . $set[$i]['hora_sorteo'] . "</th>"; 
 }?>
 </tr>
  </thead>

   <?php
    $consulta2 = $DB_con->query("SELECT 
   animalitos.id,
   animalitos.numero,
   resultado.id,
   resultado.fk_animalitos,
   resultado.fk_hora_sorteo,
   resultado.fk_dias,
   resultado.fecha,
   hora_sorteo.id,
   hora_sorteo.hora_sorteo,
   dias.id,
   dias.dias
           FROM animalitos 
                INNER JOIN resultado ON animalitos.id=resultado.fk_animalitos  
                INNER JOIN hora_sorteo ON resultado.fk_hora_sorteo=hora_sorteo.id
                INNER JOIN dias ON resultado.fk_dias=dias.id
                WHERE resultado.fk_dias='6'  ORDER BY resultado.id ");
    for ($set2 = array (); $row = $consulta2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $set2[] = $row);
    ?>
    <?php 

    $set2 = array_chunk($set2, 8);
    foreach($set2 as $set){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($set as $v){
    echo "<td>" . $v['numero'] . "</td>"; 
     }
     echo "</tr>";
     }

      ?>
      </table>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

esto debería resolver tu problema, pero creo que deberías replantear la forma en que obtienes los datos.

```
       for ($set2 = array (); $row = $consulta2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $set2[] = $row);    
       echo '<tr>';    
       for($b=0;$b<count($set2);$b++){
            if ($b%8==0){
                 echo '</tr>';
                 echo '<tr>';
             }
           echo "<td>" . $set2[$b]['numero'] . "</td>";
       }
       echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: gracias amigo por tu respuesta he implementado lo que me dijo pero ahora se me repiten los resultados y queda como una pirámide

Comment: puedes agregar el resultado de tu query?

Comment: (https://prntscr.com/fi9zw2)

Comment: pero que resultado te da tu "Select"?

Comment: @yoclens actualice la respuesta

Comment: ahora no me muestra los resultados de la segunda semana del día jueves debería mostrarme dos resultados del día jueves pero solo me muestra un resultado